# Git-Bash in Windows Terminal don't work when split screen

Tags: windows-10, git-bash, windows-terminal

I have just installed git-bash on Windows Terminal. However, there is a problem that appears, when I split the screen, the first screen becomes don't work anymore. Only the new one is working.

[image: image description here]

Comment: What's the `commandline` you set for your git-bash profile?

_How_ doesn't it work? Is it not accepting keystrokes? Does splitting panes for other profiles work?